# delete contents of a binary file before writing to it again

Tags: java, binary, randomaccessfile

I have  a simple write method using RandomAccessFile to write an ArrayList of Strings in a *.bin file.  Depending on user input, the size of the ArrayList is going to change after every user access.  This is the only method that writes to this file.

```
@FXML protected void writeToFile(){

    try(RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(fileName, "rw")){

        // file.setLength(0);
        file.seek(0);
        file.writeUTF(wordsArrayList.toString());
        file.close();

    }catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("error writing from writeToFile()");
    }
}
```

How can I clear the contents of the file (not delete the file and create a new one) using RandomAccessFile before writing to it again in order to avoid *.bin files like below? Setting the length to zero doesn't seem to work.

[image: *.bin file view]

Comment: *Why* do you not want to delete the existing file and create a new one? And what happened if you called `file.setLength(0)`?

Comment: What's wrong with `setLength(0)`?

Comment: I guess I assumed that creating a new file is bad practice and setLength(0) doesnt account for a list of strings shorter than the previous and still leaves remnants of the previous string.

Comment: Why are you using a RandomAccessFile in the first place, and not simply a FileOutputStream (wrapped by a Writer)? RandomAccessFile is useful when you need to access random locations in the file. But you don't.

Comment: I've asked myself that as well, but it is a part of the assignment.